# Dynamically Declaring Variables

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

This project is just for my own satisfaction, so I'm not really looking for other libraries to accomplish this. I'm trying to make an HTML element library:

```
var ElementLibrary = function() {};
(function() {
    var _concatArray = [,'Element'];
    var _varArray = [
        'html',
        'head', 'title', 'base', 'link', 'meta', 'style',
        'script',
        'body', 'section', 'nav', 'article', 'aside', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'hgroup', 'header', 'footer', 'address', 'main',
        'p', 'hr', 'pre', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'ul', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'figure', 'figcaption', 'div',
        'a', 'em', 'strong', 'small', 's', 'cite', 'q', 'dfn', 'abbr', 'data', 'time', 'code', 'var', 'samp', 'kbd', 'sub', 'sup', 'i', 'b', 'u', 'mark', 'ruby', 'rt', 'rp', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'span', 'br', 'wbr',
        'ins', 'del',
        'img', 'iframe', 'embed', 'object', 'param', 'video', 'audio', 'source', 'track', 'canvas', 'map', 'area', 'svg', 'math',
        'table', 'caption', 'colgroup', 'col', 'tbody', 'thead', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'td', 'th',
        'form', 'fieldset', 'legend', 'label', 'input', 'button', 'select', 'datalist', 'optgroup', 'option', 'textarea', 'keygen', 'output', 'progress', 'meter',
        'details', 'summary', 'command', 'menu'
    ];
    var _l = _varArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < _l; i++) {
        _concatArray[0] = _varArray[i];
        ElementLibrary.prototype[_concatArray.join('')] = document.createElement(_varArray[i]);
        ElementLibrary.prototype[_varArray[i]] = function() {
            return this[_concatArray.join('')].cloneNode(false);
        };
    }
})();
```

The way I had originally begun to write it would have ended up at over 400 lines, so I wanted to do it in a more compact way. The good news, it partially works. If I do:

```
var el = new ElementLibrary();
el.pElement // <---that is correctly a paragraph element
```

However, that's not really the intended use. I want to get a shallow clone off of the single prototypal property like:

```
var el = new ElementLibrary();
el.p() // <---this is where I run into trouble
```

If I call any of my ElementLibrary functions, it ONLY returns the last element in my array (menu in this case). Why does every function return only the last element when the properties are all declared properly?

EDIT: I added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBPhr/) and pulled the _concatArray business out.

Solution:

```
var ElementLibrary = function() {};
(function() {
    var _varArray = [
        'html',
        'head', 'title', 'base', 'link', 'meta', 'style',
        'script',
        'body', 'section', 'nav', 'article', 'aside', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'hgroup', 'header', 'footer', 'address', 'main',
        'p', 'hr', 'pre', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'ul', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'figure', 'figcaption', 'div',
        'a', 'em', 'strong', 'small', 's', 'cite', 'q', 'dfn', 'abbr', 'data', 'time', 'code', 'var', 'samp', 'kbd', 'sub', 'sup', 'i', 'b', 'u', 'mark', 'ruby', 'rt', 'rp', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'span', 'br', 'wbr',
        'ins', 'del',
        'img', 'iframe', 'embed', 'object', 'param', 'video', 'audio', 'source', 'track', 'canvas', 'map', 'area', 'svg', 'math',
        'table', 'caption', 'colgroup', 'col', 'tbody', 'thead', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'td', 'th',
        'form', 'fieldset', 'legend', 'label', 'input', 'button', 'select', 'datalist', 'optgroup', 'option', 'textarea', 'keygen', 'output', 'progress', 'meter',
        'details', 'summary', 'command', 'menu'
    ];
    var _l = _varArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < _l; i++) {
        var _temp = _varArray[i];
        var _tempElement = _temp + 'Element';
        (function(t, te) {
            ElementLibrary.prototype[te] = document.createElement(t);
            ElementLibrary.prototype[t] = function() {
                return this[te].cloneNode(false);
            };
        })(_temp, _tempElement);
    }
})();

var el = new ElementLibrary();
alert(el.p());
```

Comment: It seems like it'd be a **lot** less weird to simply use string concatenation to form the property names (`_varArray[i] + "Element"` in other words).

Comment: I'll also give this a shot. It seems like both suggestions are correcting the same problem.

Comment: Yes that's true; I haven't had enough coffee this morning to realize that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you create in that loop do not refer to "frozen" versions of "_concatArray".  They all share a reference to the very same array.

Wrap them in another function:

```
ElementLibrary.prototype[_varArray[i]] = (function(ca) {
  return function() {
    return this[ca.join('')].cloneNode(false);
  };
})(_concatArray);
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is still there, but you're on to something. They do seem to reference the same thing.

Comment: @Llepwryd they *definitely* reference the same array; that's how JavaScript works.

Comment: I added a fiddle, but even with some changes I still have the same problem. Maybe _varArray is the source of the problem, but then I don't know why the properties are all declared correctly.

Comment: +1 I take it back, a combination of both your suggestions fixed it. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/jBPhr/2/

Comment: @Llepwryd You're going to have exactly the same problem with "_tempElement". JavaScript variables are scoped at the function level.  All of those functions will share the same variable if you don't wrap them in another function as in my code above. (*edit* ah OK good :-)